# Method favorite that accepts two parameters: a Scanner from the console

Tags: java, methods

This is a program of writing a static method named favorite that accepts two parameters: a Scanner from the console, and a favorite letter represented as a one-letter String. The method repeatedly prompts the user until two consecutive words are entered that start with that letter. The method then prints a message showing the last word typed.

For example:

```
Looking for two "y" words in a row.
Type a word: hi
Type a word: bye
Type a word: yes
Type a word: what?
Type a word: yellow
Type a word: yippee
"y" is for "yippee"
```

I have written the favorite method already and its almost complete but I am now getting problems

i. calling this method in the main method.
ii. In the favorite method I need to make the case-sensitive like if the favorite letter is a, I should not stop prompting if the user types words that start with a capital A.

HERE IS MY CODE SO FAR.

```
public class favoriteLetter {

    public static void main(String[]args){


    }

    public static void favorite(Scanner console, String favletter){

        System.out.println("Looking for two \""+ favletter+"\" words in a row.");

        int count = 0;
        String word = "";
        while(count<2){

            System.out.println("Type a word: ");
            word = console.next();
            if (word.startsWith(favletter))
            {
                count++;
            }
            else
            {
                count = 0;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("\""+favletter+ "\" is for \"" +word+"\"");

    }

    }
```

Comment: word.toLowercase().startsWith(favletter) and save the favletter as lowercase letter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your favorite function is correct as java treats uppercase and lowercase letters different and for the first point you can call your function like this.

```
favorite(new Scanner(System.in), "a");
```